# What does the .fit() method of a picture do?

Tags: asymptote

What does the .fit() method of a picture do in the following Asymptote code?

```
picture pic1;
real size=50;
size(pic1,size);
fill(pic1,(0,0)--(50,100)--(100,0)--cycle,red);

picture pic2;
size(pic2,size);
fill(pic2,unitcircle,green);

picture pic3;
size(pic3,size);
fill(pic3,unitsquare,blue);

picture pic;
add(pic,pic1.fit(),(0,0),N);
add(pic,pic2.fit(),(0,0),10S);

add(pic.fit(),(0,0),N);
add(pic3.fit(),(0,0),10S);
```

This is from the manual of Asymptote:
http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Frames-and-pictures.html

The result is

[image]

Without the `.fit()` method the code fails with the error

```
fun.asy: 15.4: no matching function 'add(picture, picture, pair, pair)'
```

The function does not seem to be documented anywhere. There is however a cryptic comment on that same page dealing with fitting pictures to frames which says

> A picture pic can be explicitly fit to a frame by calling
>
> frame pic.fit(real xsize=pic.xsize, real ysize=pic.ysize,
>                 bool keepAspect=pic.keepAspect);

I am not sure I understand this properly. 
Is there a simple example which can explain
the behaviour of this function?

Comment: Basically this method converts a `picture` to a `frame`. In a `picture`, there are two coordinate systems -- one for drawing, and one for pen nibs. So, for instance, if you multiply a picture by `scale(2.0)`, the lines get longer but not thicker. Once you convert a `picture` to a `frame`, there is only one coordinate system; if you scale the `frame` size, it rescales both the length and the thickness of lines. (And if you rescale a `frame` by different `x` and `y` scales, your dots become ovals.)

Comment: Ok thanks! Can you also explain how the add function is used in the example above? From the asymptote terminal, I found that the appropriate function type of the add function being used is `<void add(picture dest=<default>, frame src, pair position, pair align, bool group=<default>, filltype filltype=<default>, bool above=<default>)>
` I am not sure what `position` and `align` mean. If I had not seen the output of the code above, I would have guessed that the lower left corner of the triangle would have been directly vertically over the center of the circle, but it isn't so in the output.